# Fazer um tipo de condição em tabela no MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Olá, estou montando um banco para hotel no MySql e gostaria de saber como acrescentar uma condição para data e horário de entrada  (checkin) e data e horário de saída(checkout) específico para não haver duplicidade de reservas no período reservado pelo hóspede. 
Obrigada! 
Lizypanta

Comment: Bem vindo(a), [Clique aqui e veja como funciona o SOpt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Aproveita também, e veja [como criar um exemplo Mínimo, 
Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/477535-resolvidoregistros-no-intervalo-de-2-datas/#entry1897617

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um gatilho (trigger) para ser executado antes de inserir o registro na tabela, como o exemplo abaixo, supondo que vocÊ usa a tabela "tabela_reservas" com as colunas "quarto_id", "checkin" e "checkout":

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tabela_reservas_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `tabela_reservas` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF(SELECT count(*) as total FROM tabela_reservas as tr WHERE NEW.quarto_id = tr.quarto_id AND ((NEW.checkin >= tr.checkin AND NEW.checkin <= tr.checkout) OR (NEW.checkout >= tr.checkin AND NEW.checkout <= tr.checkout)))
THEN
    -- AQUI VC IMPLEMENTA O QUE DESEJA FAZER NOS CASOS DE DUPLICIDADE (LEMBRANDO QUE ATÉ AQUI O NOVO REGISTOR AINDA NÃO FOI INSERIDO NO BANCO)
END IF;

END
```

Comment: Obg Jhonnyjks! Vou tentar aqui com sua dica!!!